# Clustering algorithm

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a set of n elements (1,000 <= n <= 100,000) and I can compute the grade of similarity between each pair, that is a value from 0 (very similar) to 1 (very different). I would like to cluster the elements based on their grade of similarity.

I thought about representing them as a graph, the elements are the vertices and the weighted edges are the similarity between them. I read about the MCL algorithm but I think it isn't the best approach since my graph is complete.

On the other hand, as there are a lot of elements, maybe computing the similarity between each pair is not the best practice (I want a fast algorithm). I also read something about leader clustering algorithms but, again, I am not sure if it is the best approach because, as far as I know, it is quite prone to fail due to its greediness (I would like something more robust).

Edit: I forgot to mention that I know a threshold for which when the comparison between two elements is higher than it, then I know that they belong to different clusters.

Comment: If I know Similarity(a,b) and Similarity(b,c), does that tell me (or allow me to bound) Similarity(a,c)?

Comment: No. Sometimes it does, but I never know when it is likely to occur

Comment: The type of clustering algorithms you might want to use (given your requirements) is probably [complete-linkage clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering) which is necessary to avoid the chaining problem. If it is more complex than that, you may have to reconsider how that "similarity" is defined - e.g. if it is originally computed by a vector of scores, you may have to use that whole vector instead of a single similarity value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any meaningful clustering is possible if `similarity(a,b)` and `similarity(b,c)` don't upper-bound `similarity(a,c)`. To demonstrate, let's consider the following simple (and extreme) example with only 3 items:

- `similarity(a,b) == 0`
- `similarity(b,c) == 0`
- `similarity(a,c) == 1`

`a` should thus be in the same cluster as `b` and `b` in the same cluster as `c`. But `a` and `c` should be in different clusters, which contradicts the previous expectations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a spectral clustering problem which has been studied in research area for a long time. Generally speaking, a spectral clustering algorithm uses the eigenvalues (aka spectrum) analysis to split the data into two or more clusters at a time. Each of this splitting is somehow globally optimized which leads to a overall good results of the final clustering.

The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering) can give more details.

PS: Commonly an element of a similarity matrix, which is a [similarity measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure) for two objects, has a smaller value for dissimilar objects and a larger value for similar ones.

Comment: An answer that amounts to 'go google it' is not a strong answer. Please provide information about the nature of the problem and a brief summary of the information. If appropriate, include references to your summary for further reading for the OP, though these references should not make up the bulk of the answer.